# Italian citizenship after marriage

Tags: citizenship

My husband, a South African citizen, was issued with a "permesso di soggiorno per motivi familiari" in January 2018.
The transcription of the marriage (which took place in the Republic of South Africa on October 1, 2016) was done at the local Comune in September 2017.
When can we apply for Italian citizenship? I am an Italian citizen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign spouse of an Italian citizen can claim Italian citizenship after **two years** legal residence in Italy (permit to stay and enrolment in an official statistics office (Anagrafe)) after the wedding;  or **three years** after the wedding if the couple live abroad (out of Italy); the timeframes are reduced by half in the presence of children born or adopted by the spouses;